# Add more than 1 role in a permission in Codeigniter function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, permissions

I'm currently working in re-adapt an ERP system that already has some functions, most of them are locked only to admin users, but I want to unlock it also to the staff, the edit fucntion look like this:

```
public function can_action($table, $action, $id, $permission = null)
{
    $role = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $result_info = $this->db->where($id)->get($table)->row();
    if (!empty($permission) || $role != 1) {
        if (!empty($result_info)) {
            if ($result_info->permission != 'all') {
                $get_permission = json_decode($result_info->permission);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            if (is_object($get_permission)) {
                foreach ($get_permission as $user => $v_permission) {
                    if (!empty($v_permission)) {
                        foreach ($v_permission as $v_action) {
                            if ($user == $user_id) {
                                if ($v_action == $action) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The $role != 1 means Admin i want to add the role 3 as well

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try `if (!empty($permission) || $role != 1  || $role != 3)`?

Comment: hello yeah i did and it doens't work